# Restrict IntelliJ only to only inspect current file

Tags: intellij-idea, inspections, intellij-inspections

IntelliJ IDEA performs a lot of checks while typing code. This is ok so far but I realized that it is doing this for all visible files.

I like to have many files open parallel but this causes my cpu to be high performance heating system. I see a significant difference between having one or ten editor tabs open.

Is there an option that IntelliJ only checks the currently selected file?

---

Update: Since there is probably no option I raised a ticket: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-193407

Comment: Not that I'm know of. You could look at this [tutorial](https://www.vojtechruzicka.com/intellij-idea-tips-tricks-improving-performance/) to improve the performance of Intellij as an alternative.

Comment: Yes please check the tips from the mentioned above blog post. And if you experiencing performance issues, I'd rather report it at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with CPU snapshot taken at the moment of it's high usage: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241235

Comment: @Marcel Wait a minute, are you talking tabs that are opened but not selected? Because that sounds like a bug.

Comment: @Meo Yes I have several editor windows placed next to each other. Sometimes it is technically just one window but with splitted tabs. But only one can have the focus (=is selected).

Comment: @Marcel Sure, understand. Sounds like a feature, but you could report that. I was worried you meant visible tabs without visible editors.

Comment: What do you mean by "a lot of checks?" What is being checked? Are you referring to its code-completion features?